# How to install `yq` with Mach-O 64-bit executable? I got error `bad CPU executable`

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew

I'm not very familiar with Mac system, so I used `brew install jq` and `brew install yq`,
then I got:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/jq
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/jq: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ file /usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq: Mach-O executable i386
```

Then when I run something and it gave me an error:

```
/usr/local/bin/xxx/lib/yq: Bad CPU type in exectable
```

I'm thinking this can be fixed if I can install `yq` with `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`, does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to ask Homebrew why their formula is installing a 32-bit executable.

Comment: Especially as Homebrew does not support 32 bit executables now